# Unable to store pic link into database

Tags: php, mysql, image, pdo

I am trying to upload my pic into folder and file link store into database although file store in folder but unfortunately doesn't store link in database. Please see where I am doing mistake.

```
<?php
include('dbconnection.php');
if(count($_FILES["file"]["name"]) > 0)
{
 sleep(3);
 for($count=0; $count<count($_FILES["file"]["name"]); $count++)
{
  $file_name = $_FILES["file"]["name"][$count];

  $tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]['tmp_name'][$count];

  $file_array = explode(".", $file_name);

  $file_extension = end($file_array); 
  if(file_already_uploaded($file_name, $connect))
{   
$file_name = $file_array[0] . '-'. rand() . '.' . $file_extension;  
}  
$location = 'files/' . $file_name;
  if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location))
  {
   $stmt= $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_image (image_name) VALUES (:image_name)");
   $stmt->bindParam(':image_name', $file_name); 
   $stmt->execute();
  }
 }
}

function file_already_uploaded($file_name, $connect)
{
 $statement = $connect->prepare("SELECT image_name FROM tbl_image WHERE image_name = '".$file_name."'");
 $statement->execute();
 $number_of_rows = $statement->rowCount();
 if($number_of_rows > 0)
 {
   return true;
 }
 else
 {
   return false;
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: There may be another tbl_image field that requires a value that you are not setting. If you have phpmyadmin or similar tool, try run the SQL string that fails to see clearly the problem.

Answer (score 0):

store the image name as location with file name:

```
$location = 'files/' . $file_name;
  if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location))
  {
   $stmt= $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_image (image_name) VALUES (:image_name)");
   $stmt->bindParam(':image_name', $location.'/'.$file_name); 
   $stmt->execute();
  }
```

Comment: after above changes i got following error
Uncaught Error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in D:\xampp\htdocs\uploads\upload.php:22

Comment: You can use one variable for it like $filePath = $location.'/'.$file_name; and then store $filePath variable in image_name parameter

Comment: I already have done above instructions like
$img = $location.'/'.$file_name; 
and Then pass $img

Comment: okay thanks. Please give an upvote if it works for you. thanks

Comment: You cannot bind param to a string. bindParam function requires you to pass to it just a variable, in `by reference` context.

Comment: but don't know why when i declare the variable still didn't work.